# Dynamically set table cells children div heights to 100% its row height

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to "dynamically" update the height of each `div`to be equal to its row parent

I have this very simple code that does the job good but throughout all rows. So what I am finallygetting is setting all `td divs` with the greatest **value within the whole table**, which I don't want.

What I want is, to set all divs with the greatest height **within the same row**

Any suggestions?

```
function setdivHeights() {
    var maxHeight = -1;
    $('tbody tr td div:last-child').each(function() {
        if ($(this).height() > maxHeight) {
            maxHeight = $(this).height();
        }
    });
    $('tbody td div:last-child').height(maxHeight);
    $('tbody td div:last-child').addClass('cell');
}
```

and this is a simplified sample of my `html` code:

```
<table class="tablesorter" id="list">
    <thead></thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td><div>1</div></td>
            <td><div>2</div></td>
            <td><div>3</div></td>
            <td><div>4</div></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><div>a</div></td>
            <td><div>b</div></td>
            <td><div>c</div></td>
            <td><div>d</div></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: I don't know if javascript is useful here. With only CSS you can. `<td>` will occupy all height in the same row (what you need), and you can set `height: 100%;` for the `td div` selector that will ocuppy 100% the height of the `<td>`. No javascript needed.

Comment: I tried that at the begining, but for some reason, 100% for the `divs` doesn't fill the whole `td`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just do it per row instead of for all rows in your selector:

```
function setdivHeights() {
    trs = $('tbody tr');
    trs.each(function(){
        var maxHeight = -1;
        $(this).find('td div:last-child').each(function() {
            if ($(this).height() > maxHeight) {
                maxHeight = $(this).height();
            }
        }).height(maxHeight).addClass('cell')
    }) 
}
```

Comment: thank you very much for your solution. It worked fine, however, when I resize the browser`minimize` it works fine, but the when I re`maximize` it back, height stays set to the greatest values. Any suggestions for solving this??

Comment: Not sure what you mean but you should run this function on window resize

Answer (score 0):

Hi I have no idea if I understood you, but if you have a height and width on the td's, you can simply give to the dive with css a height and width of 100% and it should fill it. The red border is the dimension of the td's and the blue box is the filled div... I think there is no JS needed for such a solution, because, when you give the css 100% of height, it takes the value of it's parent element, in this example the div would take the 20px of his parent, the td, and fill it. If I did'nt understood you're question, than sorry :)

```css
.tablesorter tbody tr td {
  height: 20px;
  width: 70px;
  border: 2px solid red;
}

.tablesorter tbody tr td div {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<table class="tablesorter" id="list">
    <thead></thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td><div>1</div></td>
            <td><div>2</div></td>
            <td><div>3</div></td>
            <td><div>4</div></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><div>a</div></td>
            <td><div>b</div></td>
            <td><div>c</div></td>
            <td><div>d</div></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

try to use `border-collapse: collapse` and `border-spacing: 0`

```
table {
  width: 200px;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-spacing: 0;

}
tr td {
  padding: 0;
  width: 70px;
  height: 50px;

}
tr td div {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: green;
}
```